# Proving $A \to (B \vee C) \therefore (A \to B) \vee (A \to C)$

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

In P.D. Magnus. forallX: an Introduction to Formal Logic (pp. 154), appears this exercise:

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{A \to (B \vee C)}{
  \fitch{A}{
 B \vee C \\
   \fitch{B}{
     \fitch{\neg(A \to B)}{
       \fitch{A}{
         B 
        } \\
        A \to B \\
        \bot
      } \\
      A \to B \\
      (A \to B) \vee (A \to C)
    }\\
    \fitch{C}{
     \fitch{\neg(A \to C)}{
       \fitch{A}{
         C 
        } \\
        A \to C \\
        \bot
      } \\
      A \to C \\
      (A \to B) \vee (A \to C)
    }\\
    (A \to B) \vee (A \to C)
  }
}
$

In this stage, I reached the conclusion but I am inside a sub-proof. Is there a way to successfully prove this argument?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(A%E2%86%92(B%E2%88%A8C))%E2%86%92((A%E2%86%92B)%E2%88%A8(A%E2%86%92C))) might help.

Comment: Thank you, Shaun. How do I interpret the result given by Tree Proof Generator ?

Comment: You're welcome. It assumes the negation of the formula then applies a bunch of contradiction-hunting rules to it. If every branch of the tree contains a contradiction, then the original formula is a tautology. I'm not sure how it translates to the proof method in question though. It just offers a different perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$
Remark: Your subproof is somewhat convoluted. Compare:
$$\fitch B{\fitch{\neg (A\to B)}{\fitch AB\\A\to B\\\bot}\\\neg\neg(A\to B)\\A\to B\\(A\to B)\vee(A\to C)}\qquad\raise{7.25ex}{\fitch B{\fitch AB\\A\to B\\(A\to B)\vee(A\to C)}}$$

---

There are two ways to derive a disjunction.

1. constructively derive one of the disjuncts, or
2. use an indirrect proof (reduce the negation to absurdity).

You are having trouble doing (1), therefore you should attempt an indirect proof.

Assume $\neg((A\to B)\vee(A\to C))$ and place your proof inside this context.

$$\fitch{~~1.~A\to(B\vee C)}{\fitch{~~2.~\neg((A\to B)\vee(A\to C))}{\fitch{~~3.~A}{~~4.~B\vee C\hspace{20ex}\textsf{Conj.Elim 3,1}\\\fitch{~~5.~B}{\fitch{~~6.~A}{~~7.~B\hspace{20ex}\textsf{Reiteration 5}}\\~~8.~A\to B\hspace{17ex}\textsf{Conj.Intro. 6-7}\\~~9.~(A\to B)\vee (A\to C)\hspace{4ex}\textsf{Disj.Intro. 8}\\10.~\bot\hspace{22.5ex}\textsf{Neg.Elim. 9,2}\\11.~C\hspace{22.5ex}\textsf{Explosion 10}}\\\fitch {12.~C}{}\\13.~C\hspace{25ex}\textsf{Disj.Elim. 4,5-11,12-12}}\\14.~A\to C\hspace{22ex}\textsf{Conj.Intro 3-13}\\15.~(A\to B)\vee(A\to C)\hspace{9ex}\textsf{Disj.Intro 14}\\16.~\bot\hspace{27.5ex}\textsf{Neg.Elim. 2,15}}\\17.~\neg\neg((A\to B)\vee(A\to C))\hspace{6.5ex}\textsf{Neg.Intro. 2-16}\\18.~(A\to B)\vee(A\to C)\hspace{11.5ex}\textsf{Double Neg.Elim. 17}}$$

Comment: Thank you, Graham. When you assume $C$; where are you discharging it ?

Comment: @F.Zer With the disjunction elimination.  $\dfrac{\Gamma\vdash B\vee C\quad \Gamma,B \vdash C \quad \Gamma,C\vdash C }{\Gamma\vdash C}$.

Comment: Another possible way to prove a disjunction would be via a derived rule of "converse of disjunctive syllogism": if $\Gamma, \lnot A \vdash B$ then $\Gamma \vdash A \vee B$.  So in this case, if you assume $\lnot(A \rightarrow B)$ and also $A$, then you can conclude $\lnot B$ and also $B \vee C$, and by disjunctive syllogism then you conclude $C$.

Comment: Thank you very much for annotating every step, @GrahamKemp ! I thought that, in order to discharge $C$, you would need to use Repetition Rule. Perhaps, it is not strictly necessary ?

Comment: @GrahamKemp, why did you justify line 17 with Neg. Introduction insead of IP ?

Comment: Indirect Proof is a derived rule, comprised of the fundamental rules of *negation introduction* and *double negation elimination* in the system I'm most familiar with using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assume the conclusion is false and aim for a reductio proof (this is pretty standard if you want to prove a disjunct and can't individually prove one of the disjuncts).

Here's one way of then completing the proof, more or less by brute force (since at every step you do a fairly standard thing).

$A \to (B \lor C)\\
\quad\quad \neg((A \to B) \lor (A \to C))\\
\quad\quad \quad\quad \quad\quad (A \to B)\\
\quad\quad \quad\quad \quad\quad ((A \to B) \lor (A \to C))\\
\quad\quad \quad\quad \quad\quad \bot\\
\quad\quad \neg(A \to B)\\
\quad\quad \quad\quad \quad\quad (A \to C)\\
\quad\quad \quad\quad \quad\quad ((A \to B) \lor (A \to C))\\
\quad\quad \quad\quad \quad\quad \bot\\
\quad\quad \neg(A \to C)\\
\quad\quad\quad\vdots\\
\quad\quad A\\
\quad\quad \neg B\\
\quad\quad \neg C\\
\quad\quad (B \lor C)\\
\quad\quad\quad \vdots\\
\quad\quad \bot\\
\neg\neg((A \to B) \lor (A \to C))\\
((A \to B) \lor (A \to C))$

The first dots are filled in using standard moves from the two negated conditionals, the second dots by $\lor$-elimination on $B \lor C$.